# Kubernetes - can a service use another service without me writing the latter's IP in the former's code?

Tags: kubernetes

In the following guide:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-kubernetes-in-under-3-hours-a-detailed-guide-to-orchestrating-containers-114ff420e882/

The architecture looks like this:
[image]

The frontend (which is served from SA-Frontend) sends requests to SA-WebbApp.
In a dev environment, I believe both would run on different ports on `localhost`, but in production, as the guide suggests at the very bottom, we have to realize the IP address of SA-WebApp:

```
minikube service list
|-------------|----------------------|-----------------------------|
|  NAMESPACE  |         NAME         |             URL             |
|-------------|----------------------|-----------------------------|
| default     | kubernetes           | No node port                |
| default     | sa-frontend-lb       | http://192.168.99.100:30708 |
| default     | sa-logic             | No node port                |
| default     | sa-web-app-lb        | http://192.168.99.100:31691 |
| kube-system | kube-dns             | No node port                |
| kube-system | kubernetes-dashboard | http://192.168.99.100:30000 |
|-------------|----------------------|-----------------------------|
```

Edit the code of the frontend to use it:

```
analyzeSentence() {
        fetch('http://192.168.99.100:31691/sentiment', { /* shortened for brevity */})
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState(data));
    }
```

Then rebuild the static files, rebuild the Docker image, repush it to the hub, edit the deployment yaml for the frontend and execute `kubectl apply -f` on it.

Is there any way to make the frontend take the IP from some kind of configuration / discovery instead of me manually inserting it and rebuilding the whole thing?

Comment: If you have KubeDNS in your cluster then you can use the internal hostname of the service for the frontend to make requests to the webapp over the internal container overlay network. If they’re in the same Kubernetes namespace then you just need first segment of the hostname, not the FQDN, since the part of the FQDN after the first segment is a search domain. So you would just need to configure frontend to talk to “webapp” instead of an IP address or a FQDN address.

Comment: Generally you'd use [the DNS name of the Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services) and not worry about what specific IP addresses are involved.

Comment: +1, I was just going to link you to the doc David Maze linked to help better explain what I explained in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by community members [Amit Kumar Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1061413/amit-kumar-gupta) and [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) please refer to:

1. [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services).
2. [Connecting Applications with Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/)
3. Your guide in the section [Kubernetes in Practice — Services](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-kubernetes-in-under-3-hours-a-detailed-guide-to-orchestrating-containers-114ff420e882/). There are two topics in your example:

   - Applying a label to all the pods that we want our Service to target and
   - Applying a “selector” to our service so that defines which labeled pods to target.